# match css selectors that are not on the same level

Tags: css

I need to match the selectors that I put down in the image but I can't find any css property to do it
The point is that I need that when the input-radio is checked the button is seen in another color, any css expert that can help me?

Thanks

```
    <div class="radio" id="uniform-28">
      <span class="checked">
      <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_1" value="28" id="28"></span>
    </div>
    <label for="28">5/6</label>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYTBd.png)

Comment: Please add script you use to mark span checked... you should make parent div checked instead, than you can use `.radio.checked + label { ... your styles for label ... }`

Comment: this is a Prestashop theme and I don't know where is checked span
Really product.tpl code is here:
                **<input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" value="{$id_attribute}" id="{$id_attribute}" {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} checked="checked"{/if}  />                <label for="{$id_attribute}">{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</label>**

but final code is that I paste originally and not is equal !! I dont found the error @skobaljic

Comment: Than you cannot do it with css only, can show you jQuery solution if you want to?

Comment: @skobaljic you want see the file product.js of theme ?

Comment: In case it handles this radio buttons.... than just post the relevant code (probably the part that contains `.attribute_radio`)

Comment: @skobaljic url de js in pre-production is http://norkid.dev.trestristestigres.com/themes/TheStyle/js/product.js

my changes for see radio.buttons like square buttons I have in my  pc in localhost

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select parent elements via css, therefor you have to use script and toggle element classes. One way to do it:

```js
$('.attribute_radio').each(function(i) {
    var thisRadio = $(this);
    var thisName = thisRadio.attr('name');
    var groupRadios = $('.attribute_radio[name='+thisName+']');
    thisRadio.on('change', function() {
        groupRadios.each(function(j) {
            var thatRadio = $(this);
            thatRadio.closest('.radio').toggleClass('radio_checked', thatRadio.is(':checked'));
            /* You could also target the label itself this way: */
            var labelId = thatRadio.attr('id');
            var thatLabel = $('label[for='+labelId+']');
            thatLabel.toggleClass('label_checked', thatRadio.is(':checked'));
        });
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.radio {
    display: none;
}
.radio + label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    min-width: 50px;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    border: 3px solid #444;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.radio_checked + label {
    background: yellow;
}
.label_checked {
    /* Any styles */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    Group 1
</p>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-27">
  <span class="checked">
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_1" value="27" id="27">
  </span>
</div>
<label for="27">4</label>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-28">
  <span class="checked">
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_1" value="28" id="28" checked="checked">
  </span>
</div>
<label for="28">5/6</label>
<p>
    Group 2
</p>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-37">
  <span class="checked">
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_2" value="37" id="37" checked="checked">
  </span>
</div>
<label for="37">XS</label>
<div class="radio" id="uniform-38">
  <span class="checked">
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_2" value="38" id="38">
  </span>
</div>
<label for="38">S</label>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/1h3k0jqw/34/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restructure your DOM and that will make it easy for you to apply CSS.

How about this?

```
<div class="radio" id="uniform-28">
  <span class="checked">
    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="group_1" value="28" id="28"/>
    <label for="28">5/6</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

And then you can apply style you want

```
.checked label {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This way you don't have to do extra wotk with JS and CSS.
Also you might have to change your existing CSS if you want use above HTML.